# Object inside object destructuring ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Middleware.js**

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var db = require('./mongoose.js');

var middleWareFunctions = {}; //define middleware object (cont. functions)

var authenticate = function (req, res, next) {

    var token = req.header('x-auth');
    db.user.findByToken(token).then((result) => {

        if (!result) { //No found user.
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        req.user = user;
        req.token = token;
        next(); //Otherwise the other route won't run.
        ///The above req gets passed in to main route (this is the middle-ware).
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(401).send();
    });

};

middleWareFunctions.authenticate = authenticate;

module.exports = middleWareFunctions;
```

**server.js**

```
var {authenticate} = require('Middleware.js');
```

Is this accurate? I used this as my middleware in my actual routes and it did not seem to work. How do I refer to this object?

I want to retrieve the `authenticate` function inside of `middleWareFunctions` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function authenticate (req, res, next) {

    var token = req.header('x-auth');
    db.user.findByToken(token).then((result) => {

        if (!result) { //No found user.
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        req.user = user;
        req.token = token;
        next(); //Otherwise the other route won't run.
        ///The above req gets passed in to main route (this is the middle-ware).
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(401).send();
    });

}
```

Have you tried something like this?
You can export any number of objects/functions and access them in other files like
`import { authenticate } from 'middleware';`

if you export something like

`export default function auth() {}`

You'll get it like

`imoort auth from 'middleware'`